# Thinkpad T530 Wifi Issues on 14.10

Tags: wireless, thinkpad

Several times a day my Wifi mysteriously stops working. If I disable Wifi and re-enable it, it starts working again just fine. I have several other devices in the house that don't have this problem at all. This may have started happening on the upgrade to 14.10 but I am not totally sure. Can anyone give me some tips to diagnose the problem? Thanks.

Comment: I had the same problem , this thread 1st answer solved it:  http://askubuntu.com/questions/454427/network-issues-since-trusty

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the same issue I'm having. I tried this anyway and it didn't change anything :(

Comment: Looking at /var/log/syslog, I consistently see this when it disconnects:

`Nov 26 08:35:00 wt-tpad kernel: [  269.974121] wlan0: AP f8:ed:a5:95:77:70 changed bandwidth, new config is 2437 MHz, width 2 (2447/0 MHz)
Nov 26 08:35:01 wt-tpad kernel: [  270.281237] wlan0: AP f8:ed:a5:95:77:70 changed bandwidth, new config is 2437 MHz, width 1 (2437/0 MHz)`

Comment: i'm having the same issue on 15.04. works fine on my 14.04 device