# Ubuntu 13.10, 14.04, 14.10 hangs on at boot

Tags: 14.04, boot, 13.10

I would not duplicate any thread but here the stuff is rather obscure.
I'm a not so clever linux user even if I used it since many years, but at a user level, not guru.

The last distro I've used without (important) problems is the 13.10.

Few days before this Christmas I decided to move toward the 14.10, first upgrading to 14.04 with the normal upgrade procedure, when my PC started to show anomalies at the boot.

The main behavior is: boot -> login screen and the whole thing freeze up. No way to use keyboard nor mouse or trackpad. Or (alternative behavior) login with success, then newly login page (I tried to put a wrong password and the login behave correctly, saying password incorrect)

I was able to do a full backup and then I decided to try to install from scratch Ubuntu 14.04 from CD (it was not so easy because more and more time the install sequence hanged on) and now I have a 14.04 working only in recovery mode.

[I attach a syslog file](http://www.betaingegneria.it/download/syslog.tgz) containing the histories of 3 boots, each one with different warnings/errors, hoping this could be enough to understand where the problem is. I can add information as needed.

Details on my HW:

Linux jsbach 3.13.0-32-generic #57-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jul 15 03:51:08 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

```
product: Vostro 3700 (To be filled by O.E.M.)
   product: 07VWR8
      product: Intel(R) Core(TM) i5 CPU       M 460  @ 2.53GHz
         product: 8JSF25664HZ-1G4D1
         product: 8JSF25664HZ-1G4D1
      product: Core Processor DRAM Controller
         product: Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port
            product: GT216M [GeForce GT 330M]
            product: GT216 HDMI Audio Controller
         product: Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2
            product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3
            product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4
            product: MMC/SD Host Controller
            product: R5U2xx (R5U230 / R5U231 / R5U241) [Memory Stick Host Controller]
            product: R5C832 PCIe IEEE 1394 Controller
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller
         product: 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge
         product: Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller
         product: 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem
      product: Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers
      product: Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder
      product: Core Processor QPI Link 0
      product: Core Processor QPI Physical 0
      product: Core Processor Reserved
      product: Core Processor Reserved
         product: ST9320423AS
         product: DVD+-RW AD-7585H
   product: DELL TY3P40B


  *-network               
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Broadcom Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:12:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 01
   serial: c0:cb:38:7f:86:8c
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.141 (r415941) ip=192.168.1.38 latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
   resources: irq:17 memory:fb400000-fb403fff

*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:13:00.0
   logical name: eth0
   version: 03
   serial: f0:4d:a2:a3:4f:ef
   size: 10Mbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168d-2.fw latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
   resources: irq:46 ioport:d000(size=256) memory:d2c04000-d2c04fff memory:d2c00000-d2c03fff memory:fb300000-fb31ffff

00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 18)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor PCI Express x16 Root Port (rev 18)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 18)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset HECI Controller (rev 06)
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset High Definition Audio (rev 06)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 1 (rev 06)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 2 (rev 06)
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev 06)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev 06)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev 06)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset USB2 Enhanced Host Controller (rev 06)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev a6)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 5 Series Chipset LPC Interface Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset 6 port SATA AHCI Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset SMBus Controller (rev 06)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 5 Series/3400 Series Chipset Thermal Subsystem (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GT216M [GeForce GT 330M] (rev a2)
01:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GT216 HDMI Audio Controller (rev a1)
12:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4313 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
13:00.0 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 03)
14:00.0 SD Host controller: Ricoh Co Ltd MMC/SD Host Controller (rev 01)
14:00.1 System peripheral: Ricoh Co Ltd R5U2xx (R5U230 / R5U231 / R5U241) [Memory Stick Host Controller] (rev 01)
14:00.3 FireWire (IEEE 1394): Ricoh Co Ltd R5C832 PCIe IEEE 1394 Controller (rev 01)
ff:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture Generic Non-core Registers (rev 05)
ff:00.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QuickPath Architecture System Address Decoder (rev 05)
ff:02.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Link 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.1 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor QPI Physical 0 (rev 05)
ff:02.2 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
ff:02.3 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Core Processor Reserved (rev 05)
```

I don't know what to do anymore, I hope to find some enlightening hint from you.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do any of the live iso's boot successfully either?

Comment: I only can run the 14.04 LTS in debug mode. Now enabling debug info I got a more detailed log [here](http://www.betaingegneria.it/download/syslog.1.tgz). I put 2 newlines between reboots for clarity. Note on line 9966 immediately before a restart...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when troubleshooting boot problems you will want to edit your kernel boot parameters in GRUB.  You may need to hold shift after the BIOS splash to show the GRUB menu.  Press 'e' to edit the boot parameters followed by 'end' to move to the end of the line.  Replace 'quiet splash' with 'verbose' or if you want even more info 'debug'.

Try disabling KMS by adding 'nomodeset'.  Also 'noacpi' can sometimes help.  Although the nouveau drivers have come a long way in recent years, you may still want to install the latest nvidia drivers from the repo with 'sudo ubuntu-drivers devices' followed by 'sudo apt-get install nvidia-###' from the list.

Comment: The live iso has more boot options to try too, under F6 in it's menus.

Comment: Thanks Justin! It was the nvidia driver (proprietary) that should be installed. I followed your instructions (without disabling KMS), simply sudo apt-get install nvidia-331. And this is the 3rd painless reboot I do. So I'm confident that the problem is resolved. Thank you again!

Answer (score 0):

Saw a lot of

```
 intel ips 0000:00:1f.6: failed to disable graphis turbo
```

errors, if this is a desktop is there onboard video or a different video card to try? Maybe anything else that could be unplugged to try "troubleshooting" if it's incompatible hardware...

Maybe just trying a different kernel would work... the one in Ubuntu 13.10 seemed ok but I don't think Ubuntu supports that version anymore. I'm not sure about how to change Ubuntu's kernel right now either, but a Debian Stable live ISO might work for testing an older one. I read that CrunchBang was based on Debian stable & it *might* use an older kernel for testing too.

And some wifi messages too, but could be "harmless" [Network Issues since Trusty](https://askubuntu.com/questions/454427/network-issues-since-trusty)

Comment: Thank you Xen2050! Me too I noticed that message. I have a Dell Vostro 3700 I'm not sure to be able to unplug the video card :-) But the funny thing today is: the whole system has started without problems!!! But now I'm trying to read out the logs, just before to change my job! I let you all know. Ciao and Happy New Year if we will not see again here!